# Ant Ivy: How to retrieve source code for all levels of dependencies?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I tried to configure Ivy to download source code for dependencies.  It works, but only for the top-level dependency.  Maven will get sources for all levels of dependencies.  How can I do this using Ivy?

Here is my **ivy.xml** file:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.ubs" module="IMQuant"/>
    <dependencies defaultconfmapping="*->default,sources">
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.maven.surefire" name="common-java5" rev="2.17"/>
        <dependency org="com.googlecode.kevinarpe-papaya" name="kevinarpe-papaya" rev="0.0.15"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Here is my **retreive** statement:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${libs.dir}/ivy/all/[artifact]-[revision]-[type].[ext]" />
```

Above, dependency **kevinarpe-papaya** requires Google Guava.  I see the JAR downloaded (actually a bundle), but I don't see the sources.  I checked my Ivy cache.  The sources are also missing for Google Guava.

Also, dependency **junit** requires Hamcrest (core).  Again, I see the JAR downloaded, but I don't see the sources.  (Also, I checked my Ivy cache.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to specify the type:

```
type="sources"
```

E.g.:

```
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" type="sources" rev="4.11"/>
```

If you want to retrieve different types, mention the same dependendy multiple times:

```
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" type="sources" rev="4.11"/>
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" type="jar" rev="4.11"/>
```

Comment: xml parsing: ivy.xml:209:56: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'type' is not allowed to appear in element 'dependency'. in file:/c:/git/ews/ews/ivy.xml